Best Practices for Dynamic Origin Handling in API Middleware - FastApi
I'm currently working on an API project where I've implemented middleware to restrict access to a single origin, which is reserved for the client. However, I've encountered an issue where my API also needs access, but the origin is dynamic and cannot be fixed in the middleware.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:
I have an API built using FastAPI.
I've implemented middleware to enforce policies and restrict access to a single origin.
The origin is reserved for the client, but I also need the API to have access.
Given this scenario, I'm looking for recommendations on how to handle dynamic origins in API middleware. Specifically, I'm interested in exploring different options or strategies that would allow me to accommodate the dynamic nature of the API's host while still maintaining security and restricting access appropriately.
Some considerations:
Are there any middleware libraries or frameworks that offer built-in
support for handling dynamic origins?

What are the best practices for managing dynamic origins in API
middleware?

How can I ensure that the API maintains security while allowing
dynamic access?

Any insights, recommendations, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You might find this answer and this answer helpful.
